# Merge 2 linq queries, using result from 1 to continue search

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Currently I've written this:

```
    public Task<List<BulkmailAnnouncementModel>> GetBulkmailAnnouncementsByPackageTrackingId(string packageTrackingIdentification)
    {
        var announcement = await Context.BulkmailAnnouncement
            .Include(x => x.Tarras)
            .Include(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications)
            .Where(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications.Any(y => y.Value == packageTrackingIdentification) &&
                        x.AuditReportIndicator != true)
            .FirstAsync();

        return await Context.BulkmailAnnouncement
            .Include(x => x.Tarras)
            .Include(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications)
            .Where(x => x.CustomerOrderId == announcement.CustomerOrderId && x.CustomerPartyAccountId == announcement.CustomerPartyAccountId)
            .ToListAsync();
    }
```

I'm trying to combine these 2 statements into 1. I want to query the database just once, because having the result of the first query load in memory and then using it for the 2nd is inefficient.

The result I want is a list of `BulkmailAnnouncements` which all have the same `customerOrderId` and `CustomerPartyId`.

In order to find out which `customerOrderId` and `CustomerPartyId`, I first need to find 1 `bulkmailAnnouncement` which has a `packageTrackingIdentification` equal to the parameter of the method. then use that `bulkmailAnnouncement` to find all other announcements with the same `customerOrderId` and `CustomerPartyId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alas you didn't specify your requirement in words. So I have to look at your code to see what you want.

Apparently you have an input parameter `packageTrackingIdentification` and a queryable sequence of `BulkmailAnnouncements`.

Every `BulkmailAnnouncement` has a Boolean `AuditReportIndicator` and zero or more `PackageTrackingIdentifications`.

Your first query, fetches (several properties of) the first `BulkmailAnnouncement` that has a true `AuditReportIndicator` and at least one `PackageTrackingIdentification` that equals your input parameter `packageTrackingIdentification`

Your 2nd query fetches (several properties of) all `BulkmailAnnouncements` that have certain properties (CustomerOrderId and CustomerPartyAccountId) equal to the ones you fetched from your first query.

You could group all `BulkmailAnnouncements` into groups that have the same `certain properties`. So you know that all `BulkmailAnnouncement` in a group have the same values for `certain properties`

Keep the first group that has at least one `BulkmailAnnouncement` with a true `AuditReportIndicator` and at least one `PackageTrackingIdentification` that equals your input parameter `packageTrackingIdentification`.

Note that the latter part is equal to what you would have selected in your first query. The result is one group. You know that all `BulkMailAnnouncements` in this group have the same value for `certain properties`, and there are no `BulkMailAnnouncements` with the same values for `certain properties` that are in other groups. Besides you know that the group also contains at least one `BulkMailAnnouncement` with true `AuditReportIndicator` and at least one `PackageTrackingIdentification` that equals your input parameter `packageTrackingIdentification`. Hence your requested result equals the items you want.

```
var result = BulkmailAnnouncements.GroupBy(

   // Key: make groups with same "certain properties"
   announcement => new
   {
       CustomerOrderId,
       CustomerPartyAccountId,
   })
   // Result: groups of BulkMailAnnouncements with equal "certain properties"

   // keep only those groups that have at least one BulkMailAnnouncement
   // that has both a true AuditReportIndicator and at least one
   // PackageTrackingIdentification that equals packageTrackingIdentification
   .Where(groupOfBulkMailAnnouncements =>
         groupOfBulkMailAnnouncements.Any(bulkMailAnnouncement =>
            bulkMailAnnouncement.AuditReportIndicator &&
            bulkmailAnnouncment.PackageTrackingIdentifications
                 .Any(packageTrackingId == packageTrakcingIdentification)))

   // from the remaining groups, take the first or default
   .FirstOrDefault(); // or use async version
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the `Where` predicate to the second query:

```
return await Context.BulkmailAnnouncement
        .Include(x => x.Tarras)
        .Include(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications)
        .Where(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications != null 
            && x.PackageTrackingIdentifications.Any(y => y.Value == packageTrackingIdentification) 
            && x.AuditReportIndicator != true)
        .ToListAsync();
```

Or call `Include` on the first:

```
var announcement = await Context.BulkmailAnnouncement
        .Include(x => x.Tarras)
        .Include(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications)
        .Where(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications != null 
            && x.PackageTrackingIdentifications.Any(y => y.Value == packageTrackingIdentification) 
            && x.AuditReportIndicator != true)
        .FirstAsync();
```

> The result i want is a list of BulkmailAnnouncements which all have the same customerOrderId and CustomerPartyId. In order to find out which customerOrderId and CustomerPartyId i first need to find 1 bulkmailAnnouncement which has a packageTrackingIdentification equal to the parameter of the method. then use that bulkmailAnnouncement to find all other announcements with the same customerOrderId and CustomerPartyId.

Then group the results by the `CustomerOrderId` and `CustomerPartyAccountId` properties and take the first group, e.g.:

```
return (await Context.BulkmailAnnouncement
    .Include(x => x.Tarras)
    .Include(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications)
    .Where(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications != null 
        && x.PackageTrackingIdentifications.Any(y => y.Value == packageTrackingIdentification) 
        && x.AuditReportIndicator != true)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.CustomerOrderId, x.CustomerPartyAccountId })
.FirstAsync()).ToArray();
```

Comment: It's not about the includes, it's about first looking for packageTrackingIdentification and then using that result to search again for everything using the CustomerOrderId of the result found in the first querry

Comment: @Vincent: Try to group the results and grab the first group. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to use Concat() method like below

```
var announcement = await Context.BulkmailAnnouncement
        .Where(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications.Any(y => y.Value == packageTrackingIdentification) &&
                    x.AuditReportIndicator != true)
        .FirstAsync();

var announcement2 = await Context.BulkmailAnnouncement
        .Include(x => x.Tarras)
        .Include(x => x.PackageTrackingIdentifications)
        .Where(x => x.CustomerOrderId == announcement.CustomerOrderId && x.CustomerPartyAccountId == announcement.CustomerPartyAccountId)
        .ToListAsync();

var resultAnnouncement = announcement.Concat(announcement2);
return resultAnnouncement;
```